# External SVG as Google maps api marker - Yes or No

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

Let's say I've got a map app and I'm creating markers out of some external user data. Users are able to define paths to their custom images which they want to use as marker icons. My problem is svg files. After reading through related stackoverflow threads and trying suggested solutions I still can not make that work on Firefox and IE.

Some say that Google Maps API doesn't support external svg files as icons and the only way to make it work is to use path notation, but some said it's possible to use external file, but using a google.maps.Icon object.

Question:
At that point of time do we have exact yes or no answer to whether we can use external svg as a marker icons and how.

Here  is link to my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nb6q0Lk/7/) with a simple example.

I'm creating marker like below

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    title: 'SVG Marker',
    icon: {
      url: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0250/8090/files/R_final.svg',
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
      //scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
      size: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
    },
    map: map

  });
```

Chrome - works.

Firefox , IE - markers do not show.

If I uncomment scaleSize property , I've got weird scaling on IE . Firefox still doesn't display.

Path notation doesn't seem like an option for me, as long as you can point me to the way of extracting it from the files.

Appreciate your input on this.

Answer (score 2):

At least for Firefox, uncomment scaledSize, and add this property to the marker :

```
optimized:false
```

This still works on Chrome, but I had no way to test it on IE.

You can see it on [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tuurqhy7/).

*Note :* I tweaked yours (no callback/async/defer, and immediate call of initMap) because it didn't even show the map on Firefox.